# SPRING MVC JPA duplicate key value violates unique constraint

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

i'am working on a web application and i'm currently trying to save some data in my DB. The problem is that cascaseType.ALL doesn't merge with existing childs and absolutely don't no why so i got the error of the title. After some research i've seen that it was possible to specify with an SQL query : ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING but i don't know how to specify this in annotations. Here is my code for saving :

```
Domain d1 = ImmutableDomain.builder().name("Domain1").id("1").build();
        Domain d2 = ImmutableDomain.builder().name("Domain2").id("2").build();
        Domain d3 = ImmutableDomain.builder().name("Domain3").id("3").build();
        Domain d4 = ImmutableDomain.builder().name("DevOps").id("4").build();
        Domain d5 = ImmutableDomain.builder().name("RH").id("5").build();

        Category c1 = ImmutableCategory.builder().name("Category1").id("10").addDomains(d1).build();
        Category c2 = ImmutableCategory.builder().name("Category2").id("11").addDomains(d2).build();
        Category c3 = ImmutableCategory.builder().name("Category3").id("12").addDomains(d3).build();
        Category c4 = ImmutableCategory.builder().name("BackEnd").id("13").addDomains(d4).build();
        Category c5 = ImmutableCategory.builder().name("FrontEnd").id("14").addDomains(d4).build();
        Category c6 = ImmutableCategory.builder().name("Recruitment").id("15").addDomains(d5).build();
        Category c7 = ImmutableCategory.builder().name("Administration").id("16").addDomains(d5).build();

        Skill s1 = ImmutableSkill.builder().name("Skill1").id("20").addCategories(c1).build();
        Skill s2 = ImmutableSkill.builder().name("Skill2").id("21").addCategories(c2).build();
        Skill s3 = ImmutableSkill.builder().name("Skill3").id("22").addCategories(c3).build();
        Skill s4 = ImmutableSkill.builder().name("Java").id("23").addCategories(c4).build();
        Skill s5 = ImmutableSkill.builder().name("C").id("24").addCategories(c4).build();
        Skill s6 = ImmutableSkill.builder().name("Angular").id("25").addCategories(c5).build();
        Skill s7 = ImmutableSkill.builder().name("Compatbilité").id("26").addCategories(c6).build();
        Skill s8 = ImmutableSkill.builder().name("HeadHunter").id("27").addCategories(c7).build();

        s1 = skillService.save(s1);
        s2 = skillService.save(s2);
        s3 = skillService.save(s3);
        s4 = skillService.save(s4);
        s5 = skillService.save(s5);
        s6 = skillService.save(s6);
        s7 = skillService.save(s7);
        s8 = skillService.save(s8);
```

here are my entites : domains :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ATS_DOMAIN")
public class DomainEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 42)
    @Column(name = "domain_name", length = 42, nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;
```

categories :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ATS_CATEGORY")
public class CategoryEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 42)
    @Column(name = "category_name", length = 42, nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "ATS_CATEGORY_DOMAIN", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "domain_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<DomainEntity> domains = new ArrayList<DomainEntity>();
```

skills :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ATS_SKILL")
public class SkillEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 42)
    @Column(name = "skill_name", length = 42, nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "ATS_SKILL_CATEGORY", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "skill_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<CategoryEntity> categories = new ArrayList<CategoryEntity>();
```

i precise that i try cascadeType.MERGE + cascadeType.PERSIST and tried cascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE but none of them worked.

Comment: Why are you using a SequenceGenerator for the Long ids, and then set the id("1") explicitly?

Comment: because i think that when i save in cascade it creats an object with an other id with same name so it can't merge. But i'm absolutely not sure !